Does @jitsi/react-native-sdk supports react native expo?
I am trying to integrate Jisti react-native SDK into my expo project and having an error
Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
 
LOG  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'JitsiMeeting' of undefined]

Does @jitsi/react-native-sdk support react native expo?
I need to have video calling, screen share, white board in my react native expo application, is it possible to achieve this with this API?
This is the code I have in my application.
import { JitsiMeeting } from '@jitsi/react-native-sdk/index';
 <JitsiMeeting
        room={'ThisIsNotATestRoomName'}
        serverURL={'https://meet.jit.si/'}
        token={'dkhalhfajhflahlfaahalhfahfsl'} />

"@jitsi/react-native-sdk": "2.0.2"


May be it is need to use development build to use this staff.
Try to use npx expo prebuild to create native folders (ios and android). Next run  npx expo run:android (or ios) to start. I hope it will help you.
